# Viewing the value of reference string in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I noticed that during debug mode if a string is passed by reference to a method then upon hitting a breakpoint the hover does not display the content of the string on the other hand a string that isnt passed by reference works fine. Any idea on how i can read the content of a string on a breakpoint in debug mode ? I am using VS2008

```
For example
void myfunct(std::string& val)
{
  --->breakpoint here - hover over val variable will not display value
}
```

However

```
void myfunct(std::string val)
{
  --->breakpoint here - hover over val variable will display value
}
```

Comment: Sanity check: Was the code also compiled in Debug mode, and not Release?

Comment: Yes. It was compiled in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can the name `val` to the "watch" window in debug mode (if it's not in "auto" or "local"). I'm not sure if mouseover will work, though.